"Permission denied" error when using sudo for writing image to /dev/sdb on Debian
I am confused as to why I am getting the following error:
$ sudo zcat firmware.A20-OLinuXino-Lime2.img.gz partition.img.gz > /dev/sdb
bash: /dev/sdb: Permission denied

Shouldn't sudo be able to run any command? Why can't it run this one?
I am attempting to install Debian on my A20-OLinuXino-Lime2.
Thank you so much for any support you can provide.

Duplicate of Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on.

note how the error message comes from bash, not zcat

zcat doesn't need sudo, but the redirection does.
Try
zcat firmware.A20-OLinuXino-Lime2.img.gz partition.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb

